# Can Elasticsearch provide a composite score of a group aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

Given an index of documents, is there a way to use aggregation to provide some total group score instead of just the count of documents in that group?

The documents in the index look something like this. There will be thousands of different categories.

```json
{
   "category": "A",
   "title": "...",
   "description": "...",
   ...
}
{
   "category": "B",
   ...
}
{
   "category": "A",
   ...
}
```

I am using the query below to aggregate the results into a grouping of categories. This gives me the expected aggregation results.

```json
GET {index-name}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "..."
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results of that query are truncated below.

```json
"hits": {
  "hits": [
     { 
        "_id": ...
        "_score": 6.59
        "_source": { ... }
     }, ...
  ]
},
"aggregations": {
  "group_by_category": {
    "buckets": [
      {
         "key": "A",
         "doc_count": 191
      },
      {
         "key": "B",
         "doc_count": 39"
      }
      ...
  }
}
```

I am looking for a result with a "_score" in each "bucket" in the aggregate—ideally, a way to define how that score is calculated.

Desired aggregations object:

```
"aggregations": {
  "group_by_category": {
    "buckets": [
      {
         "key": "A",
         "doc_count": 191,
         "_score": 4.32
      },
      {
         "key": "B",
         "doc_count": 39",
         "_score": 4.16
      }
      ...
  }
}
```

I can do a score aggregation after I get the results but my end goal for this use case is to not return the results at all, only the aggregation by the category.

Answer (score 0):

In further research, I found a solution. Within an `aggs` element, I can nest another `aggs` element. Since the score is a special field getting that value is slightly different. Use the `script: _score` element instead of using a `field: <field_name>` element.

Below is a sample query that will return a `sum` of the `_scores` of the hits within that aggregation as well as a way to get a set of general `stats` from the group.

```
GET {index-name}/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "..."
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      }
      "aggs": {
        "score_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        },
        "score_stats": {
          "stats": {
            "script": "_score"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The response is exactly what I'm looking for.

```json
...
 "aggregations": {
    "group_by_category": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 191,
          "score_stats": {
            "count": 191,
            "min": 2.1325550079345703,
            "max": 6.593973159790039,
            "avg": 4.1415355392775615,
            "sum": 791.0332880020142
          },
          "score_sum": {
            "value": 791.0332880020142
          }
        },
     ...
```